# Function returning undefined after first log

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set up an image swapper function.  Here is my code so far:

```
var imageChanger = function(start, end) {

var start = 1;
var end = 22;

return {
    count: function(url) {

        var self = this;

        if(start > end) {
            start = 1;
        }

        console.log(url);
        console.log(start++);

        imageSwapper = setTimeout( function() {
            self.count();
        }, 2000)

    },
    stopCount: function() {
        clearTimeout(imageSwapper);
    }
}

}
```

As you can see, this is a function that takes two parameters.  It then returns an object of it's own with two methods.  When I call the `count` method after the initial `imageChanger` function call and pass a parameter to `url` it only logs what I pass one time and then when the `setTimeout` function runs, undefined subsequent times.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.  Why is this `count` function returning undefined after the first log??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the setTimeout, you should call `self.count` with the `url` argument instead of no-argument, i.e.

```
self.count(url);
```